# Changing Background using JSON Object

Tags: jquery, json

I want to change the Background of a divbox when music is played while the path is in the json object, but it always takes the last entry of the Background with this code:

```
for (var i in data.Music){
      var id= "a" + i;
      var bg="url(" + data.Music[i].Background + ")";
      document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('play', function(){
         $( "#Background" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
         $('#Background').css("background-image", bg); 
         });
         $( "#Background" ).fadeIn( "slow");

    }); 


  }
```

Json

```
"Music":[{"Title":"Bring mich nach Haus",  
                      "Source":"\"Music/08. Bring mich nach Haus.mp3\"",
                      "Background":"\"Backgrounds/Faun.jpg\""
                     },
                     {
                        "Title":"100 Ways to Hate",
                        "Source":"\"Music/11. 100 Ways to Hate.mp3\"",
                        "Background":"\"Backgrounds/FFDP.jpg\""
                     }
```

Adding the Audio tags :

```
for (var i in data.Music)
    {
        console.log(i);
        outputmusic +=  data.Music[i].Title + "<br />" +    "<audio controls id=\"a"+i+"\"><source src=" + data.Music[i].Source + " type=\"audio/mpeg\">" + "</audio> <br />"  
    }

document.getElementById("Music").innerHTML=outputmusic;

console.log(outputmusic);
```

Comment: well what do you want? a random image? a specific one? as long as you just loop through all images in the array the last one will stay.

Comment: i'd like to get a specific Background when a specific Title is played ... added the JSON code

Comment: OK, but you are cycling through them in a `for (var i in data.Music)` loop. Don't you want a specific one?

Comment: Yeah wanted to add an eventlistener to every audiotag... added the code for the audiotags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a closure issue. Your function ends up binding to the last value of bg.

This code should work:

```
for (var i in data.Music) {
    var id = "a" + i;
    (function() {
        var bg="url(" + data.Music[i].Background + ")";
        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('play', function() {
             $("#Background").fadeOut( "slow", function() {                  
                 $('#Background').css("background-image", bg); 
             });
             $("#Background").fadeIn( "slow");
        });
    })();
}
```

Comment: Fixes the closure issue, but needed to use play instead of click

Comment: Fixed it - I was testing it so I needed to use 'click'. Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you might have a [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) problem - since you're iterating over the elements in data.Music, the last background saved into the variable 'bg' is the final background data in data.Music. However, that same 'bg' is, for lack of a better term, 'saved' thanks to the closure, and is the one that's attached as a background image when the .fadeOut() callback is called.

Possible fix:

```
for (var i in data.Music){
      var id= "a" + i;
      var bg="url(" + data.Music[i].Background + ")";
      document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('play', function(){
         var currBg = bg;
         $( "#Background" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
         $('#Background').css("background-image", currBg); 
         });
         $( "#Background" ).fadeIn( "slow");

    }); 
  }
```

Comment: Still takes the last one